# Error running sqlite3 on ruby 1.9: undefined method 'changes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ffi

Here is the error I'm getting.  It just started out of the blue

```
undefined method `changes' for #<SQLite3::Driver::FFI::Driver:0xa75235c>
```

I'm using
ruby 1.9.1p243
gem 1.3.5
rails 2.3.5
ffi 0.5.4
sqlite3 0.0.3

On ubuntu 9.10 desktop, but i've had the same problem 9.04

Anyone know what's causing this error?

Comment: I've uninstalled sqlite3 and ffi and reinstalled sqlite3-ruby and that seems to work fine.  Must be something with the new gems that doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed the bug here: http://github.com/joevandyk/sqlite3 in this commit: http://github.com/joevandyk/sqlite3/commit/0174eb6b2554072b1d8e46adae9f3fb9a5991cd7

Hopefully it'll be merged into the sqlite3 gem soon.